# Restsharp response returns null when content-type response is js

Tags: c#, api, post, restsharp

When I use `Restsharp` send post request to server, but response return content is "" (`String.Empty`), I check post request on browser I see content type response is js (not json, not txt,...). `Restsharp` can't handling it. How do I do to get content data it?

[capture resonpse on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZClv9.jpg)

my code in c#:

```
var client = new RestClient("urlPost");
client.FollowRedirects = false;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
request.AddHeader("Content-Length", "617");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0");
request.AddHeader("Host", "business.facebook.com");
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "data", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: I don't see the relationship between the client side activity and this RestSharp code. If we concentrate on the server-side, what is the HTTP status of the IRestResponse? Is the service you are hitting under your control such that you can debug it? There is not enough detail here to know why you are getting an emptly string response. What do you expect to get?

Comment: @Crowcoder , Thank you for answering my question. Do you check my capture response on browser? . I want to create a post to facebook.
I debug in chrome and can send get post to facebook with Restshap if the content returned is json or text. but there is a content request returned as js, so I can't get its data with Restsharp. status post Restsharp is "OK" but content is empty. sorry my english is not good.

Comment: Your browser is not directly calling the RestSharp code, it is making an xhr request (commonly known as ajax) to some endpoint that is not shown. It is unclear if that action is even executing the server-side RestSharp code you are showing. Again, what response do you expect to get? You are passing a literal string "data" in the request body and that seems like an unusual value.